# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception web.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a small project Spring+Hibernate+MVC IDE STS
When I create project default it's create web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

When I upgrade web.xml to version 3.1

```
   <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My project stop working and remove Maven Dependencies. When I add Maven Dependencies manually and run project it's show error

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

This is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.38</mysql.version>
</properties>
```

This is full stack trace. How I can upgrade my project or web.xml to 3.0 or 3.1?

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filialController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private az.nikoil.operlist.service.FilialService az.nikoil.operlist.controller.FilialController.filialService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filialServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private az.nikoil.operlist.dao.FilialDAO az.nikoil.operlist.service.impl.FilialServiceImpl.filialDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filialDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory az.nikoil.operlist.create.session.AbstractSessionFactory.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: az.nikoil.operlist.model.Oper.filials in az.nikoil.operlist.model.Filial.opers
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace. Your initial web project was 2.3 and didn't contain anything in the `web.xml` thus nothing was being started/picked up. When you switch to 3.0 (and not 3.1 as you indicate) things will be automatically picked up.

Comment: I added part of full stack trace, because it's more 30000 simvols.

Comment: Pls put your complete pom.xml as well. Can you also check the STS PROBLEM tab with errors showing for the project.

Comment: As far as I can say, You model class `az.nikoil.operlist.model.Filial` is missing the `opers` field. Declaring that would solve your issue I guess. Please post your `spring-hibernate.xml` which is where I guess you have used `mappedBy` attribute to map relationship between `Filial` and `Oper` model classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your web.xml should look little different:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">

</web-app>
```

Make sure you're depending on the non-conflicting versions in your pom.xml. That is for example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Finally, you should compile with Java 7 or 8:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

stacktrace says that the root cause is : spring is unable to create sessionFactory. because there is an unknown annotated property "az.nikoil.operlist.model.Oper.filials" in "az.nikoil.operlist.model.Filial.opers"

Comment: Yes, it is showing that which is obvious to the OP. Please make sure this is a comment or post an answer by editing and adding how to solve the issue.

Comment: @Lucky And i can see it, you just smartly did that in comment. Today i just leaned how to copy and paste smartly ;)

Comment: @Lucky : Just came to know that user below 50 reputation can not comment on questions. please show the way forward or tell me how to report if some gp admin discourage newbie to not answer on SO :?

Comment: Please read this Meta Post on [Why does Stack Overflow prevent new users from commenting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114534/why-does-stack-overflow-prevent-new-users-from-commenting). Also getting 50 reputation is not that hard if you are willing to contribute.Read  more about [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and how to earn it.